# Php array to longtext with new lines in database

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2

I have an array of values that i would like to save in a longtext database field, one per line.

I'm using Yii 2.

If i save it like this:

```
$object->field = implode('\n', $array);
```

Then i get it in the database as a string with \n, and i can't get it separated by a new line with

```
nl2br($value);
```

But if i save it manually inside the database with phpMyAdmin in multiple lines, it works. How can i get a text string that holds the new lines when saving to the db?

Comment: try with double quote `implode("\n", $array)` because you literally ask `\n`

Comment: `$object->field = implode("\n", $array);`  use double quotes there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php if you want to add new line then you have to use `\n` with double-quotes. So code need to be:-

```
$object->field = implode("\n", $array);
```

Example:- https://eval.in/867628